# Render template string inside createElement in plugin component in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm trying to compile template string inside `createElement` function. I need to pass template string with `<nuxt-link />`.

I've tried almost everything, including `createElement('component')` with passing "is" props with my template string and trying `Vue.compile` with a result like below:

> Vue.compile is not a function

Inside **`index.vue`**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <example :tmpl="tmpl" />
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "index",
  data() {
    return {
    };
  },
  computed: {
    tmpl() {
      return `<nuxt-link :to="${this.localePath({ name:'categories-index'}, this.$i18n.locale)}">Categories</nuxt-link>`;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Inside **`example.js`** I tried:

```js
const Example = {
  install(Vue, options) {
    Vue.component('example', {
      render: function (createElement) {
        return createElement(
          'component',
          {
            props: {
              'is': this.tmpl
            }
          }
        )
      },
      props: {
        tmpl: {
          type: String,
          default: ""
        }
      },
      data() {
        return {
        }
      },
    });
  }
};
export default Example;
```

**Also**:

```js
const Example = {
  install(Vue, options) {
    Vue.component('example', {
      render: function (createElement) {
        return createElement(
          'div',
          {
            'props': {
            }
          },
          // error: Vue.compile is not a function
          Vue.compile(this.tmpl)
        )
      },
      props: {
        tmpl: {
          type: String,
          default: ""
        }
      },
      data() {
        return {
        }
      },
    });
  }
};
export default Example;
```

And **also**:

```js
const Example = {
  install(Vue, options) {
    Vue.component('example', {
      render: function (createElement) {
        return createElement(
          'div',
          {
            // error: nuxt-link is plain html instead of link
            domProps: {
              innerHTML: this.tmpl
            },
          }
        )
      },
      props: {
        tmpl: {
          type: String,
          default: ""
        }
      },
      data() {
        return {
        }
      },
    });
  }
};
export default Example;
```

The last one renders `HTML`, but `vue` code is not compiled, so `nuxt-link` doesn't work.

I expect to render compiled `vue` code with `vue` `createElement` function (with using template string).

Comment: Cant you just pass it in component options as template instead of props?

Comment: It also doesn't work and I can't becuase in example component I will have couple of template strings.

Comment: I just had another look on your issue and i wonder if this even is a valid strategy - like you can actually createElement("nuxt-link", ... prop ... to: ... , ? is there a reason it has to be a template and not just props?

Comment: It won't be always nuxt-link, so I don't want to make a big switch inside renderFunction to detect what should be rendered.

Comment: maybe this? https://github.com/vuejs/jsx#installation

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the Vue compiler installed? (Not certain if Nuxt is missing it - see
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Runtime-Compiler-vs-Runtime-only) but `Vue.compile is not a function` might imply to me that it's missing?

Possibly something like the following:

```
// nuxt.config.js
export default {
  build: {
    extend (config, { isClient }) {
      config.resolve.alias['vue$'] = 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
    }
  }
}
```

Credits for above (https://forum.vuejs.org/t/nuxt-render-function-for-a-string-of-html-that-contains-vue-components/63645/2)